# Does Swift provides the ability to eval Swift code like Javascript does?

Tags: ios, swift

Does Swift provides the ability to eval Swift code like Javascript does? I would like to create an app that can run Swift code.

Answer (score 5):

No, it doesn't. There is a Swift JIT exposed via the REPL, but it's not (currently at least) intended for use in applications.

Answer (score 2):

I think eval() is not implemented at moment.
For REPL Shell look here [Swift Blog](https://developer.apple.com/swift/blog/?id=18)