# Convert Array<String> to String then back to Array<String>

Tags: arrays, swift, parsing, casting

say I have a variable

```
let stringArray = "[\"You\", \"Shall\", \"Not\", \"PASS!\"]"

// if I show this, it would look like this
print(stringArray)
["You", "Shall", "Not", "PASS!"]
```

now let's have an Array< String>

```
let array = ["You", "Shall", "Not", "PASS!"]

// if I convert this into string
// it would roughly be equal to the variable 'stringArray'

if String(array) == stringArray { 
    print("true")
} else {
    print("false")
}

// output would be
true
```

now say what should I do to convert variable 'stringArray' to 'Array< String>'

Comment: [This question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24111764/does-swift-provides-the-ability-to-eval-swift-code-like-javascript-does) shows that there is no `eval` operation in Swift, so you could write a little parser.

Comment: This is JSON. Use the `(NS)JSONSerialization` class.

Comment: so I'd have to regex the hell out of it? that's the only way I'm thinking of doing this right now.. sadly

Comment: @vadian no this isn't JSON because JSON is `[key:value, key:value]` whereas this is just `[value, value, value]` or am I wrong?

Comment: My first question would be: *Why* is stringArray a string and not an array? Perhaps your problem should be solved at an earlier point? – But if you have to cope with it then @vadian gave the crucial hint: It is a JSON *array* of strings.

Comment: Believe me, it **is** JSON.

Comment: okay thanks. you should post that as an answer bro I think

Comment: @MartinR just exploring some use cases

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer would be to convert the string using NSJSONSerialization

Thanks [Vadian](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5044042/vadian) for that tip

```
let dataString = stringArray.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)
let newArray = try! NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(dataString!, options: []) as! Array<String>

for string in newArray {
    print(string)
}
```

voila there you have it, it's now an array of strings

Comment: `mutableContainers` is completely useless in Swift, only to read the data it's not needed anyway.

Comment: @AhmadF I should wait for 2 days to accept my own answer

Comment: @vadian what would be the best option to use then? (optimization wise)

Comment: No options (`[]`).

Answer (score 0):

**A small improvement for Swift 4**.

Try this:

```
// Array of Strings
let array: [String] = ["red", "green", "blue"]
let arrayAsString: String = array.description
let stringAsData = arrayAsString.data(using: String.Encoding.utf16)
let arrayBack: [String] = try! JSONDecoder().decode([String].self, from: stringAsData!)
```

For other data types respectively:

```
// Set of Doubles
let set: Set<Double> = [1, 2.0, 3]
let setAsString: String = set.description
let setStringAsData = setAsString.data(using: String.Encoding.utf16)
let setBack: Set<Double> = try! JSONDecoder().decode(Set<Double>.self, from: setStringAsData!)
```